# how to add a really to a message for every digit a number has?

Tags: python

It's kind of hard to explain but basically, I'm having trouble adding the word "really" to a message for every digit a number has.

so it would be like

"That's a really (amount of really's depends on the number of digits a number has) big number!"

so if I put 1,563 it would print

that's a really really really really big number!

Comment: [str.isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) might be a starting point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I suggest:

```
num = input("Enter your number: ")

count = 0
for n in num:
    count += 1

print("That's a ", "really "*count, "big number!", sep="")
```

Comment: that does work, but how does it work? It's to help me remember it.

Comment: He is counting the number of digits in the input by iterating over the input. Then for printing `really`  the number of times, he wrote the code `really * count`. Here count is number of digits in the input. In python, `string*n` prints the string n number of times. For example, `'a' * 3 `prints `aaa`. In the same way if you give input `1521`, count will be `4`. So, `'really'* count` will be `really really really really`

Comment: First you assign a number to a variable `num`. Then you create the `count` variable and set it to zero. Then you create a loop, that iterates through every digit in num; for every digit in num the `count` variable increases by one. And then you just print your sentence, with the word "really" multiplied by the variable `count`. This multiplication will print the word "really" the number of times the variable `count` says. Does that make sense? :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple, but hacky sollution could be this one:

```
number = int(input("Enter your number: "))

start = "That's a "
end = "big number!"
print(start + 'really ' * len(str(number)) + end)
```

Comment: Oh, sorry for the misunderstanding but I need it to be asked to the user, then they put a number and it prints the amount of really's for every digit the user put in

Comment: @BrandonHunt Done!

Comment: I'm so sorry but could you please explain what len does? It's how I remember things

Comment: @BrandonHunt len gets the length of a string